# Treeview re-select node by code after use

Tags: c#, treeview

When selecting a treenode in my WinForm treeview, it gets highlighted with the blue background to indicate it is selected.
Once the user hits a button, the selected node gets used in some code. In this example, when the button is pushed, the node moves up an instance.

But once the code has executed, the selection is lost. Now the user have to re-select the node by hand and hit the button again to move it up again.
So what i would want, is that the node gets re-selected after the code has executed.

i tried doing that with this code, but that does not seem to have any effect on the selection:

```
        TreeNode t = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        //do something
        Extensions.MoveUp(treeView1.SelectedNode);

        //re-select ?
        treeView1.SelectedNode = t;
```

Is there some other way to set the selection again by code after executing my method ?

EDIT (**SOLVED** - Not deleting post in case sombody in the future is looking for the same thing):

All i had to do was cast the focus as the final step:
`treeView1.Focus();` did the trick

Comment: The Node never was deselected. But by default windows hides unfocused selections. So even better: Set `treeView1.HideSelection = false;`

Comment: I think it was deselected, as hitting the button again did nothing (so there is no selection?)

Comment: I doubt it, especially if setting the Focus did the trick. did you try my way?